# Google Workspace - many shared drives and users - is there a better management tool?

Tags: google-drive

We use Google Workspace, with many shared (team) Drives, and many users. Is it possible to use another method to handle the user rights? I'm thinking of uploading a CSV or a Python script.

Comment: Maybe have a look at Github?